# RODBC::sqlSave() creating table, Warning: truncated to 255 bytes in column?

Tags: r, database, oracle, odbc, rodbc

I am using `RODBC` to try and write a new table (a local data frame) to an Oracle database. The issue I am dealing with is that many of the fields are character variables, with lengths longer than 255 characters. I ran this code to initialize the table, per the `RODBC` vignette:

```
sqlSave(channel=conn, dat=SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME)
```

Where `conn` is an R object set up using `odbcConnect` and `SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME` is the name of the local data frame. R returned warning messages, and all of them said that

> …truncated to 255 bytes in column…

The `RODBC` vignette mentions that many systems default to varchar(255) for characters. However, when I call `sqlTypeInfo()` on the `conn` object, it says that `varchar2` has a `COLUMN_SIZE` of 4000.

**How can I write this data frame to the database as a table, without truncating the character strings?** I believe I could write a SQL query using `sqlQuery` to create this table manually, but I have about 175 columns, and do not want to write out information for every single column.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when writing a data frame to a sql server db using the sqlSave function in RODBC.

It was solved through setting the column type to take more data before running the sqlSave command. I used varchar(500) and it did the trick.

If you were creating a table from R with a single column containing a long string, this is what worked for me:

```
    sqlQuery<-c('CREATE TABLE YourTable (ColumnName varchar(500));')
    channel <- odbcConnect("YourTable")
    sqlQuery(channel, paste(sqlQuery))
    close(channel)
```

After that writing to that table using sqlSave should work:

```
    sqlSave(odbcConnect("YourTable"),dataFrame,append=TRUE)
```

If you still get the truncated warning, try setting the varchar value to something greater than 500

Comment: What if my table is going to be, say, 300 variables? Using this approach, do I need to specify every single column, then?

Comment: hmmm sounds painful. How about trying to use sqlQuery<-c('CREATE TABLE YourTable ',paste0('(ColumnName',seq(1:300),' varchar(500));'))

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlsave(channel=conn, dat=SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME, varTypes=c(column_name="varchar(500)"))
```

though i'm unsure what the easiest way of getting c(column_name="varchar(500)") full of all your relevant columns is